# Getting routes of a child component in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I'm no Aurelia master and much more of a beginner.
So far i got no solution for my problem, but i think there must exist an hopefully easy way to do the following:

I got a very basic structure with the app.js and some components (e.g. admin.js ...).
Because i would like to have a navigation for the routes of all components, i need to get those routes into my app.js.
Simple, or stupid question: How do i achieve this?
I tried to simply inject the components, but i have no acces to the router attribute, no matter what i do.

Example admin component router:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.map([
      { route: '', name: 'default', moduleId: 'components/admin/default/default' },
      { route: 'roles', name: 'roles', moduleId: 'components/admin/roles/roles', title: 'Rollenverwaltung' },
      { route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: 'components/admin/users/users', title: 'Nutzerverwaltung' },
      { route: 'employees', name: 'employees', moduleId: 'components/admin/employees/employees', title: 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}
```

What i tried in my app component

```
static inject() { return [AuthService, Admin]; }

constructor(authService, admin) {
  this.auth = authService;

  this.adminRouter = admin;
}
```

I am aware that as long i did not load the component, the router of the admin would be empty anyway. But even if the component is loaded, the router object is undefined.

[A not running Gist](https://gist.run/?id=b90c5fcbde8098c1395f1d9f3d00a01f) to better show what i want (hopefully)

Maybe i am getting something basicly wrong here and don't understand the way aurelia or even js works?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to do. Would you mind providing a gist that reproduces your problem? Use this as a starting point https://gist.run/?id=7542e061bc940cde506b

Comment: So i added a small gist https://gist.run/?id=b90c5fcbde8098c1395f1d9f3d00a01f
But i am still not sure if this fully states my point or helps in any way, because i am a total rookie.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get access to the router if the `Admin` component itself was not composed, and even then the parent would not "inherit" the routes from `admin`.

If you wanted to define routes around your application and then pull them in to one place perhaps something like this would be useful for you -

parent.js

```
import {Admin} from './admin';

export class Parent {
  static inject = [Admin];
  constructor(admin) {
    this.admin = admin;
    this.admin.routes.forEach(route => {
      this.router.addRoute(route);
    }
  }
}
```

admin.js

```
export class Parent {
  routes = [
    { route: '', name: 'default', moduleId: 'components/admin/default/default' },
    { route: 'roles', name: 'roles', moduleId: 'components/admin/roles/roles', title: 'Rollenverwaltung' },
    { route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: 'components/admin/users/users', title: 'Nutzerverwaltung' },
    { route: 'employees', name: 'employees', moduleId: 'components/admin/employees/employees', title: 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung' }
  ];
}
```

Comment: ok let me see if i got this right: Your idea is just to define an array of route objects that i include in my app.js (parent) and configure the router with these arrays? Correct me if i am wrong.
Well, thats not the nicest solution i can think of, but for sure the most simple. I will give it a try. At least until i might find another solution.
Thank you!